# .htaccess rewrite to folder

Tags: apache, .htaccess

Is it possible to rewrite url to point to the "last" folder in directory?

Folder structure:

```
/path/to/site
/path/to/site/0.1.0
/path/to/site/0.2.0
/path/to/site/0.3.0
```

`http://host/path/to/site/0.1.0` show content of folder `/path/to/site/0.1.0`
`http://host/path/to/site/0.2.0` show content of folder `/path/to/site/0.2.0`
`http://host/path/to/site/0.3.0` show content of folder `/path/to/site/0.3.0`
`http://host/path/to/site` shows content of folder `/path/to/site/0.3.0`

Comment: How do you define last here?

Comment: subfolders sorted on its name

Comment: You cannot do sorting in .htaccess, better to use PHP or shell script.